# Ajax searching in Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

What I'm trying to do is to do an ajax search to a datatable.
I'm not considering the default search functionality provided by datatables for some reasons, so I created a textbox with a button for it.

On my Api, I'm sending back a Json for the javascript function

```
$("#buttonSearchDevice").on('click', function () {

    var searchString = $("#searchString").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Devices/LoadDevices",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data:
            {
                searchString: searchString
            },
        success: function (data) {

            //if (data.length == 0)
            //    $('#devicesList').dataTable().fnClearTable();
            //else {
            //    $('#devicesList').dataTable().fnClearTable();
            //    $('#devicesList').dataTable().fnAddData(data);
            //}
        }
    });
});
```

I tried the commented code to "refresh" my datatables, but no success, I'm getting the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=devicesList - Requested unknown parameter
>   'model' for row 0, column 1. For more information about this error,
>   please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Do I need to recreate the entire datatable (destroy and create) or is possible to just refresh it with the new comming data?

Comment: you can use the built in ajax and still send what every you want to the server.

Comment: no but you  do need to make sure the data being returned matches your data table defnintiion

Comment: I used the initComplete to remove the keypress event handler off of the searchbox and replaced it with one that watched for a return key press. Also added a small search button next to it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The sample below, as mentioned in my comment, takes off the event handler put on by datatable and puts on my one so it fires only on a button click.   The button is added by an event handler provided by DataTables.
Like I mentioned, I do this so the vent handler does cause an ajax call on every key press.

you can see it work here (unless it gets taken down)

http://live.datatables.net/tayelawu/1/edit

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#example").on("preInit.dt", function(){

                 $("#example_wrapper input[type='search']").after("<button type='button' id='btnexample_search'></button>");
               });


            $('#example').DataTable({
                "processing": false,
                "serverSide": true,
              "initComplete":function(){onint();},
                "ajax":{
                    url: "/examples/server_side/scripts/objects.php",
                    type:"GET",
                  data:function(dtp){
                    // change the return value to what your server is expecting
                    // here is the path to the search value in the textbox
                    var searchValue = dtp.search.value;
                    return dtp;}
                },
                "columns": [
                { "data": "first_name" },
                { "data": "last_name" },
                { "data": "position" },
                { "data": "office" },
                { "data": "start_date" },
                { "data": "salary" }
                ]
            });

        });

   // this function is used to intialize the event handlers
   function onint(){
     // take off all events from the searchfield
     $("#example_wrapper input[type='search']").off();
     // Use return key to trigger search
     $("#example_wrapper input[type='search']").on("keydown", function(evt){
          if(evt.keyCode == 13){
            $("#example").DataTable().search($("input[type='search']").val()).draw();
          }
     });
     $("#btnexample_search").button().on("click", function(){
           $("#example").DataTable().search($("input[type='search']").val()).draw();

     });
   }
```

Comment: Very useful, I didn't know about calling the search method of datatables directly from code.